# Mongodb connection failed in local with node version 18.12.0?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I am seeing one issue with node version `18.12.0` and mongodb `6.0.2`. I already build a nestjs application with mongodb. Here I use `@nestjs/mongoose(v- 9.0.2)` and `mongoose (v-6.7.0)`

Here I can see that when I upgrade node js to latest lts version then I am not able to connect to mongodb. It show an error like `unable to connect to database`.

But When I downgrade to node version `16.18.0` then it working fine. My question is that you guys already face this issue or I am only person getting this issue. If you know that then actually where is the problem occurred?

Here is my connection code-

```
MongooseModule.forRoot("mongodb://localhost:27017/nekmart", {
      connectionFactory: (connection) => {
        connection.plugin(slug, { number: true });
        return connection
      }
}),
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Had same problem after upgrading to NodeJs 18.12.1; followed other blogs/comments and apparently

changing the Uri from `mongodb://localhost:27017/test_db` to `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test_db` works.

Without getting into the specifics reasons it appears that `localhost` is rejected due to some changes in NodeJS.

Comment: What's JM Lord above comment talking about. this is not an english lesson. the answer is useful and complete

Comment: Tremmillicious is right. While using proper sentences, with punctuation and capitalization are important attributes of writing, not everyone in the world is a student of English language. Also, this is not https://english.stackexchange.com/  The answer needs to be understandable and question be addressed properly to the point. Solving problems is the reason this site exists. Thanks @yoav-agmon for the answer which solves the problem at hand.

Comment: Though this solution works, it might be better to update the mongod.conf file as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69964742/4045731 . The reason is, that the issue is due to NodeJs default to IPv6, and it's more robust to leave "localhost" instead of setting explicit IP that is only supported in IPv4.
Btw, for Windows users the mongod.conf is where the Mongo binaries are.

Answer (score 0):

> `**mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/?**`

Try with this in the new version of the node and the mongoose lib it will work fine
The same thing works in My many system which has the new version of the node.

And Most of the time entering you ipv4 ip address at the place of the localhost will make it work

And if by chance it want work then try with every ipconfig ip which is cofigured in your pc.

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe40::2830:7f6b:e242:7232%6

IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.---

Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0

Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.165.10.5

The above config depends on your computer setting

Answer (score 0):

When I modify database name inside your project it works for me:

```
# from:
DATABASE_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/yourDbName

# to:
DATABASE_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/yourDbName
```

Try and best of luck

Comment: This duplicates the accepted answer with no extra value added.